# Comparison of dendograms with dendextend::tanglegram - incorrect color asignment?

Tags: r, colors, dendrogram, dendextend

I'm using `dendextend::tanglegram()` to compare topologies of two trees. I observed occasional incorrect color-assignment of black colors to the branches which are in fact congruent (and thus should be colored). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

dend1.nwk:

```
(((((((((((((((((((((((1:1,2:1):1,3:2):1,4:3):1,(5:1,6:1):3):1,7:5):1,((8:1,9:1):1,10:2):4):1,(((((11:1,12:1):1,(13:1,14:1):1):1,((15:1,16:1):1,17:2):1):1,18:4):1,19:5):2):1,20:8):1,(((21:1,22:1):1,23:2):1,24:3):6):1,((((25:1,26:1):1,(27:1,28:1):1):1,29:3):1,30:4):6):1,(((31:1,32:1):1,33:2):1,34:3):8):1,((((35:1,36:1):1,37:2):1,(38:1,39:1):2):1,(((40:1,41:1):1,42:2):1,43:3):1):8):1,44:13):1,((((45:1,46:1):1,47:2):1,(48:1,49:1):2):1,50:4):10):1,51:15):1,((((52:1,53:1):1,(54:1,55:1):1):1,56:3):1,57:4):12):1,((58:1,59:1):1,60:2):15):1,61:18):1,62:19):1,63:20):1,(64:1,65:1):20):1,(66:1,67:1):21):1,68:23);
```

dend2.nwk:

```
(((((((((((((((((((((((1:1,2:1):1,(3:1,4:1):1):1,((5:1,6:1):1,7:2):1):1,8:4):1,9:5):1,10:6):1,(((((11:1,12:1):1,13:2):1,14:3):1,(15:1,16:1):3):1,(((17:1,18:1):1,19:2):1,20:3):2):2):1,(((21:1,22:1):1,23:2):1,24:3):5):1,((((25:1,26:1):1,(27:1,28:1):1):1,29:3):1,30:4):5):1,(((31:1,32:1):1,33:2):1,34:3):7):1,((((35:1,36:1):1,37:2):1,(38:1,39:1):2):1,(((40:1,41:1):1,42:2):1,43:3):1):7):1,44:12):1,45:13):1,(((46:1,47:1):1,48:2):1,(49:1,50:1):2):11):1,51:15):1,((((52:1,53:1):1,(54:1,55:1):1):1,56:3):1,57:4):12):1,((58:1,59:1):1,60:2):15):1,61:18):1,62:19):1,63:20):1,(64:1,65:1):20):1,(66:1,67:1):21):1,68:23);
```

Untangling and drawing tanglegram:

```
    dend1 <- ReadDendrogram("dend1.nwk") 
    dend2 <- ReadDendrogram("dend2.nwk") 
    dend2_corrected <- untangle_step_rotate_1side(dend2, dend1)[[1]]  
    tanglegram(dend1, dend2_corrected, margin_inner=3, margin_outer=0,   highlight_branches_lwd=FALSE, common_subtrees_color_branches = TRUE, axes=FALSE, highlight_distinct_edges=FALSE)
```

In the example below, see e.g. leafs 61-63 which I would expect to be colored (as this part of the tree is identical)

[image]

Comment: I don't remember the details exactly, but my guess is that it would not color a branch with only one leaf. I'm now wondering to myself if that behavior is good or not. If you think it is not, please submit an issue on github: https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend/issue
however, I'm not likely to fix this in the near future. So if you can get to have a look and fix it, and send a PR, I'd be happy to give it a look. Cheers, T

Comment: Ok, that would well explain the behavior. I'll submit issue on github (I definitely consider it a limitation for comparison of phylogenetic trees which very often contain this type of branches; I'm likely not fixing it given my R skills ;)

Comment: Submit an issue to learn if/when this is changed :)